# Error: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting error "too many values" from this code. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT (:START_DATE)|| ' TO '|| (:END_DATE) ACTIVITY_PERIOD,
        EMP_NO,
        DEPT,
        EMP_NAME,
        COUNT(*)"# OF VIOLATIONS",
      (SELECT TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI AM') AS INTIME,
       TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI') AS OUTTIME
        FROM INV.HR_ATTENDANCES A
       WHERE TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI')=:IN_TIME
       AND TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI')=:OUT_TIME)
FROM INV.EMP_ACTIVITY_HISTORY_SHIFTS        
WHERE (ATTENDANCE_DATE BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE)
AND  (TOTAL_OUT > 4 OR MINT > (case  when to_char(attendance_date,'DAY')= 'FRIDAY' then 135 else 90 end))
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ATTENDANCE_DATE,'MON-RRRR'),EMP_NO,EMP_NAME,ORG_ID,DEPT,SHIFT_ID
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

Comment: Can you please paste exact error message from Oracle ?

Comment: You can't select multiple columns and rows in subquery in select part.

Comment: Gurwinder Singh but where he does it ?

Comment: Intime and outtime

Comment: You need to do a join instead

Comment: I guess this select is unneccessary at all:       (SELECT TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI AM') AS INTIME, to me just simple: TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI AM') AS INTIME, TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI') AS OUTTIME would work just ok, but I haven't wrote in Oracle for a year or so :)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly issue is because of below code segment.

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI AM') AS INTIME,
   TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI') AS OUTTIME
    FROM INV.HR_ATTENDANCES A
   WHERE TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI')=:IN_TIME
   AND TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI')=:OUT_TIME)
```

When some subquery is used as part of `SELECT` columns, output of query should be exactly 1 row,1 column so that, output of the query can be treated as a column in overall query result.

Please check following

- Execute above part of query independently with some sample input and ensure you are getting exactly 1 row as output.
- To create single column output, you may have to

Either concatenate both columns (ex:      `TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI AM') || 'IN '||    TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI') ||' OUT' AS IN_OUTTIME` )

Or

You need to make them 2 separate sub queries as part of your outer query
ex: `SELECT  ....,(sELECT TO_CHARIN_TIME..()...FROM inv.hr_attendances..) IN_TIME, (sELECT TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME...)...FROM inv.hr_attendances..) OUTTIME from ...`

As an alternate, you can move whole sub query to `WITH` clause or `JOIN` it to main query
ex:

```
WITH IN_OUT_TIME AS (
  (SELECT TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI AM') AS INTIME,
          TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI') AS OUTTIME
          FROM INV.HR_ATTENDANCES A
          WHERE TO_CHAR(IN_TIME,'HH:MI')=:IN_TIME
          AND TO_CHAR(OUT_TIME,'HH:MI')=:OUT_TIME))
SELECT  (:START_DATE)|| ' TO '|| (:END_DATE) ACTIVITY_PERIOD,
        EMP_NO,
        DEPT,
        EMP_NAME,
        COUNT(*)"# OF VIOLATIONS",
        IN_TIME,
        OUT_TIME
        FROM INV.EMP_ACTIVITY_HISTORY_SHIFTS  , IN_OUT_TIME 
        WHERE (ATTENDANCE_DATE BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE)
        AND  (TOTAL_OUT > 4 
               OR 
              MINT > (case  when to_char(attendance_date,'DAY')= 'FRIDAY' then 135 else 90 end))`
```

Also, note your group by clause should contains the columns from your `SELECT` statement except for columns derived as group functions (ex: `count(*)`). Please revisit your group by requirement as well.

Comment: when i write 2 separate sub queries as part of  outer query then following error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: yes, you need to ensure subquery returns only 1 row. Add correct conditions in WHERE clause of sub query.  if your data contains multiple rows for required criteria, either you should look at join or using group functions based on your data processing need.

Comment: You can execute that sub query part independently and verify that result is one row and one column

Comment: i want to take both in_time and out_time from hr_attendance table so what am i do

Comment: return one column as in_out_time but multiple row

Comment: i cant understand what am i do now

Comment: Then you should use JOINs. Join `hr_attendance` table with `INV.EMP_ACTIVITY_HISTORY_SHIFTS`. Then you add appropriate conditions so that, each shift record matches with attendance record (either based on employee or any other condition), finally select only necessary columns from both table and add any `group by` conditions.

Comment: You can start with query I suggested in answer (`WITH IN_OUT_TIME....`) and then add more conditions to refine the rows you want to pick. Once you have the exact result you need, think about group by clause.

Comment: Other option is to use query `select * from hr_attendance t1, inv.emp_activity_history_shifts t2` as base. Add one condition at a time, check result and modify your query until you filter only required rows (ex: add condition `ATTENDANCE_DATE BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE` and so on. One change at a time will help you to understand how query works and conditions you add will impact query result.

Comment: when i use join then it tke time and return so many rows more than 5000...which is wrong data and replica data...becoz that query must return only 275 rows

Comment: There are not much shortcuts. Probably you will have to start with basic understanding of SQL. It wouldn't take very long to cover basic concepts like `where conditions`, `joins` etc. This could be good starting point http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp